# Prestashop 1.7. How I can use $feature.value?

Tags: php, task-parallel-library, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to show some product features in checkout page.
Screenshot:
https://yadi.sk/i/PDlGpQaaNOzqKw

But:

1. `{$feature.name}` don't work
2. `{$feature.value}` don't work
3. `{$feature.id_feature}` work
4. `{$feature.id_feature_value}` work
5. `{$product.name}` work

I try to use `{$feature|@print_r} - show`, that its Array with 3 items only:

```
 Array ( [id_feature] => 4 [id_product] => 28 [id_feature_value] => 129 )
```

and all.

How I can use `{$features.value}` there?

Answer (score 0):

Check **/templates/catalog/_partials/product-details.tpl**
from classic theme to see how features name / values are retieved from the product detail sheet.

(I am not sure **$product.grouped_features** is available in checkout also,
if not you should modify the controller to assign the data to the checkout TPL ).